# Showing a frame when collision is detected (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, frame

I have a hero character all set up with a CCSpriteBatchNode, which has all the animation and frames. But I wonder, how do I display a frame when the hero is hit (I set up collision detection already). How do I make this happen? Do I put it inside the CCSpriteBatchNode? It's not part of moving, only for special occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your hero invisible ( `[sprite setVisible: NO]`) and show another sprite at the hero's position.

More then it, you can keep this sprite in your hero class object and provide a method which will change the visible sprite when collision happens. Something like this

```
-(void) onCollision
{
    [heroMainSprite setVisible:NO];
    [heroCollisionSprite setVisible:YES];
}
```

Such solution will also preserve all your logic, that has been done before.

Answer (score 0):

When hero gets hit.. Change the texture..

```
[spr setTextureRect:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height)];
```

It needs to be in the same batch node as the rest of the animation..